# TIMESTAMP data export from snowflake to Excel

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, export-to-csv

Whenever I export the result set from a Snowflake query using the "Download a .csv for Excel" (image shown below), I find that the timestamp columns are always formatted as `2023-05-31T02:54:20Z`. This makes it difficult to format in excel as it does not work straightforward - I'm trying to format in excel as `2023-05-31 2:54:20 AM`

Any advise on how to overcome this? Is there a setting in Snowflake that we need to do **onetime** to prevent this from happening everytime? There is no problem for if the field is a date (w/o timestamp)

[image]

Comment: Curious, how did you get that download option? My version (7.38.2) does not have this. I can only download a CSV or TSV. Not sure if it's a version thing, or something else. At any rate, this might only be a bandaide, but have you tried casting your column as text before exporting?

Comment: Altering session level output format won't help you because it doesn't change the underlying data. I think the safest solutuion would be to convert that timestamp to a string of the desired format. Like so.. `select to_char(current_timestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM')`

Comment: Would it be acceptable for your use case to get the output timestamp in the downloaded CSV in 24-hour format instead of AM/PM, and then format it in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

`I find that the timestamp columns are always formatted as 2023-05-31T02:54:20Z`

It seems that Snowsight UI ("download results" button) always uses [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to format date/date time columns (regardless of [TIMESTAMP_OUTPUT_FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#timestamp-output-format) param).

An alternative approach is to use [COPY INTO location](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location):

> Unloads data from a table **(or query)** into one or more files in one of the following locations:
>
> **Named internal stage (or table/user stage)**. The files can then be downloaded from the stage/location using the GET command.

---

User stage:

```
-- unload into user stage
COPY INTO @~/export.csv
FROM (
   -- user query goes here
   SELECT 'a, a' AS col,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS col2, NULL as col3
)
 FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=CSV,
             COMPRESSION=NONE
             TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' -- desired format
             )
SINGLE = TRUE
OVERWRITE = TRUE 
HEADER = TRUE;

LIST @~/export.csv;
-- name size md5 last_modified

-- download using GET command
-- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/get
-- cannot be run inside Snowsight
GET @~/export.csv file://<file_path_local_system>;

-- cleanup
REMOVE @~/export.csv;
```

---

Named internal stage and Snowsight UI to download generated file:

```
USE <database_name>.<schema_name>;

CREATE STAGE unload DIRECTORY = ( ENABLE = true );

COPY INTO @unload/export.csv
FROM (
   -- user query goes here
   SELECT 'a, a' AS col,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS col2, NULL as col3
)
 FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=CSV,
             COMPRESSION=NONE
             TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' -- desired format
             -- other options
             )
SINGLE = TRUE
OVERWRITE = TRUE 
HEADER = TRUE;

ALTER STAGE unload REFRESH;
```

[image]

Output:

```
COL,COL2,COL3
a\, a,2023-10-26 20:33:47,\\N
```

Cleanup:

```
-- cleanup
REMOVE @unload/export.csv;

-- DROP STAGE unload;
```